# Error: basic_string::_M_construct null not valid when using haven::read_sav() - tidyverse question

Tags: r, r-haven

I have a problem when trying to read in a SPSS-file with `haven::read_sav()`. Since my knowledge of C++ is very limited and this seems to (maybe?) be an issue with C++ I'm a bit lost right now how to solve this problem or even give a good description for it. However, I will try my best and maybe somebody of you might be able to give me a hint in the right direction.

**The problem:**

I have a SPSS-file for my research work, which I would like to analyse with R and I'm using `haven::read_sav()` to read it in. However, when I run `haven::read_sav(path_to_file)` I get the following error message:

`Error: basic_string::_M_construct null not valid`

The SPSS file can be opened via SPSS without any (obvious) error messages and as far as I can see, nothing is wrong with variable/label names, etc. The problem is, that I can't share the file publicly, because it contains highly confidential information and since it contains a lot (as in: hundreds) of variables, I struggle a bit to create a similar dummy data sets for e.g. a reprex.

**My questions:**

- Does anybody know, what produces this kind of behavior?
- Is this an issue with my SPSS input and how to validate this?
- In general: any hints how to investigate this error any further?

Thank you all very much in advance and have a nice weekend :)

Comment: You probably want to talk to the maintainer(s) of `haven` here.  I fail to see how this is an `Rcpp` issue: we provide the tool, it was used to write software for which you see a bug. Have a think about it an maybe remove the `rcpp` tag.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your fast reply. I will remove the `rcpp`/`rcpp11` tags from my question. I simply don't have very much knowledge of `rcpp` in general and wasn't sure if this specific error might be related to the software or `rcpp` itself.